# Docker swarm join linux container Error - remote CA does not match fingerprint

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm

**Start docker swarm :**
docker swarm init --advertise-addr MANAGER-IP

**Join docker swarm:**
docker swarm join --token  MANAGER-IP:2377

I am using Windows 10,
it is working fine with Windows container mode, but gives below error in Linux container mode.

**Error:**

Error response from daemon: remote CA does not match fingerprint. Expected: 91030413f17ec7c023a2a796ee05a024915080ca8dfd646a597c7e966f667df6

**Docker swarm manager command: docker node ls**

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
2zf1l2o7sl2a1qka55s2vi77x *   moby                Ready               Active              Leader
```

Host name is **moby**, when running in Windows container mode it gives machine host correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configured and joined correctly you should see two hosts: one for Linux and one for Windows.

*Windows hosts cannot natively run inside the Linux hosts and vice-versa*. This means you have to have different kernels for Linux hosts and Windows hosts in the same swarm. This way they can communicate across the same Docker network.

Refer to [Docker Engine on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/docker/configure_docker_daemon) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

your token is wrong.

you can get worker token in the manager node:

```
docker swarm join-token -q worker
```

it works for me.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/